# How to perform SUM of multiple VLOOKUP values by treating N/A values as Zero?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup

I am trying to SUM multiple vlookup values as below:

Column A contains dates, and not all worksheets contain all dates, meaning that vlookup sometimes returns N/A value which in turns returns a N/A value overall.

How do I perform a SUM of all my individual lookup values so that N/A values are treated as 0?

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,Academy!A:M,13,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(A3,'AJ Blunt'!A:M,13,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(A3,BUILT!A:M,13,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(A3,Carbridge!A:M,13,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(A3,'Carter Corp'!A:M,13,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(A3,'Cleanaway - Transpacific'!A:M,13,FALSE)
```

I expect the result to be 0 only if the sum of all values is in fact zero, not if one of the values as result of vlookup returns N/A.

Answer (score 3):

So when your vlookup has an error you could put iferror() around the vlookup:

```
=iferror(vlookup(your_vlookup_detail),0)
```

which will sort the sum.

Edit : Dominique in the answer provided seems to suggest I am incorrect,...

However, both versions work, as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solar Mike, you're almost correct:

```
=ifNA(vlookup(your_vlookup_detail),0)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Dominique.

Just to clarify, is this the correct semantics for the SUM of multiples?

=ifNA(vlookup(your_vlookup_detail),0)+ifNA(vlookup(your_vlookup_detail),0)+ifNA(vlookup(your_vlookup_detail),0)

Comment: That's exactly what you can use (having always different `your_vlookup_detail`, of course :-) ).

Comment: @Dominique see the edit to my answer, **Both** versions work - yours and mine... So "almost correct"... really. And the effort you made just to copy mine...

Comment: Actually, Solar Mike was correct as per Excel Help for IFERROR: "value_if_error: The value to return if the formula evaluates to an error. The following error types are evaluated: *#N/A*, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!."; IFNA is just a specific version of IFERROR catching #N/A only.